# Loading tile-based maps using text files (2D Java Engine) Standard Libraries

Tags: java, 2d, game-engine

So I can load a 2D map using tiles using a text file, which is great and all. However, one issue I have met with this method is that I can't add objects/actors to my map since the file is a 2D grid. (The game is similar to games like zelda and pokemon.) I've tried creating an object layer so I can overlap images, but it doesn't seem to work for me. To give an example of what I want, have objects such as trees to be solid and on top of the background grass.
   I am also looking for better methods to creating these tile based maps if you want to pitch some ideas to me.

**Note: I am about beginner/intermediate at Java.

Here is my constructor for the GameState class that calls the Map.

```
public GameState(Game game) {
    super(game);
    player = new Player(game, 0, 0, 64, 64);
    map = new Map(game, "res/saves/save1.txt");
}
```

Here is the Map class (which works) that also calls the object (2nd) layer.

```
private int width, height;
public static int spawnX, spawnY;
private int[][] mapTiles;
MapObjects mapObjects;
Game game;

public Map(Game game, String path) {
    this.game = game;
    mapObjects = new MapObjects(game, "res/saves/save1_obj.txt", width, height);
    loadMap(path);
}

private void loadMap(String path) {
    String file = Utils.loadFileAsString(path);
    //Token is which number it is out of the total
    String[] tokens = file.split("\\s+");
    //Sets what is what
    width = Utils.parseInt(tokens[0]);
    height = Utils.parseInt(tokens[1]);
    spawnX = Utils.parseInt(tokens[2]);
    spawnY = Utils.parseInt(tokens[3]);

    mapTiles = new int[width][height];
    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            // (x+y*width) : calculates the nth token (+4) : The 4 prior tokens before the graph
            mapTiles[x][y] = Utils.parseInt(tokens[(x + y *width) + 4]);
        }
    }

}

public void render(Graphics g) {
    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            //Only renders what is seen.
            getMapTile(x, y).render(g, (int)(x*Tile.TILE_WIDTH-game.getCamera().getxOffset()), (int)(y*Tile.TILE_HEIGHT-game.getCamera().getyOffset()));
        }
    }
}

public void tick() {

}

//Gets the specific tile at specific coordinates.
private Tile getMapTile(int x, int y) {
    Tile t = Tile.tiles[mapTiles[x][y]];
    if(t == null) {
        return Tile.grassTile;
    }
    return t;
}
```

And lastly, the object layer that doesn't work. It does not give an error, just the overlapping objects aren't visible. I've made sure to load the object layer before the Map layer, but that doesn't seem to be the issue.

```
private int width, height;
private int[][] objTiles;
Game game;

public MapObjects(Game game, String path, int width, int height) {
    this.game = game;
    loadObjects(path, width, height);
}

public void loadObjects(String path, int width, int height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;

    String file = Utils.loadFileAsString(path);
    String[] tokens = file.split("\\s+");

    objTiles = new int[width][height];
    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            objTiles[x][y] = Utils.parseInt(tokens[(x + y *width)]);
        }
    }
}

public void render(Graphics g) {
    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            //Only renders what is seen.
            getObjTile(x, y).render(g, (int)(x*Tile.TILE_WIDTH-game.getCamera().getxOffset()), (int)(y*Tile.TILE_HEIGHT-game.getCamera().getyOffset()));
        }
    }
}

public void tick() {

}

//Gets the specific object tile at specific coordinates.
private Tile getObjTile(int x, int y) {
    Tile t = Tile.tiles[objTiles[x][y]];
    if(t == null) {
        return Tile.nothingTile;
    }
    return t;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may need a bit more info from you.

Do you use a different "container/component" to draw map tiles than you do for your objects? Because if you render objects first then they will disappear as soon as you render the map. You should draw the map first, and then do objects like so:

```
public Map(Game game, String path) {
    this.game = game;
    //swapped the order of the lines below so the map loads first:
    loadMap(path);
    mapObjects = new MapObjects(game, "res/saves/save1_obj.txt", width, height);
}
```

From what you have said then this does not work either, however if you use the same component to draw your map and objects then one will always override the other, and something will always be missing. To fix this you need to crease two separate panes, one for the map, and a transparent one that sits on top of the map that you can use to render your objects.

See this illustration as an example:

[image: Root Panes Example]

You basically need to add a new transparent "content plane" similar to the way that glass pane shown above.

Comment: hmm I switched the order, duh moment- not sure why I thought I had it in correct order but I didn't, however the object layer still doesn't seem to be loading. I'm going to work on it, and maybe try rewriting the whole thing to see if I can come up with something different. Thanks for your explanation and that neat image!